# Concatenating transform animations in Swift 3?? What is wrong?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, cgaffinetransform

So I am trying to concatenate two transform animations in swift 3. One is scale which will scale, and one is translate which will translate. I am trying to combine these two animations. I have an outlet named `ourView` which is a `UIView`. From my understanding I am doing everything right but it gives me this error

`Value of tuple type ‘()’ has no member ‘concatenating’`

Here is the code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    let scale = self.ourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    let translate = self.ourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 50)
    self.ourView.transform = scale.concatenating(translate)
})
```

What am I doing wrong? Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Why did you set transform double time?

Comment: What do you mean double time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are assigning a scale transform to `ourView`'s transform, then assigning that assignment to the scale variable. Since that assignment is a statement which doesn't take any arguments and doesn't return anything, the type of `scale` is `()`. Remove the `self.ourView.transform` stuff and you will be good to go.

```
let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
let translate = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 50)
self.ourView.transform = scale.concatenating(translate)
```